# OCaml - Reverse a list

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm trying to implement my own list module as follows :

```
type 'a my_list =
    | Item of ('a * 'a my_list)
    | Empty
```

I've already implemented several functions and am now trying to create a list reversing function for my module which would look like this :

```
let rec rev = function
    | Empty             -> (*return reversed list*)
    | Item(i, remnant)  -> (*recursive call to rev*)
```

Moreover, I'm not supposed to use list operators such as '::', '[]' and '@'.

Edit, what I tried :

```
let rec rev_append l1 l2 = match l1 with
    | Empty             -> l2
    | Item(i, remnant)  -> rev_append remnant Item(i, l2)

let rev l = rev_append l Empty;;
```

But this is not working, there is an error at the second argument passed to the recursive call : "Item(i, l2)" The error is "The constructor Item expects 1 argument, but is here applied to 0 arguments".

Comment: Is there a trick to constructing lists without using `::`?  Seems like that is essential to the definition of lists.

Comment: I edited my post to show you what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parenthesis man !

```
let rec rev_append l1 l2 = match l1 with
    | Empty             -> l2
    | Item(i, remnant)  -> rev_append remnant (Item (i, l2))
```

The compiler understood that `rev_append` was passed three argument namely `remnant` `Item` and `(i, l2)`.